# How do I use methods in jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/wiki/Docs-for-0.6), and it has a couple of methods: `containerToImage` and `imageToContainer`. How can I utilize these? I am trying to figure out what these actually do, but I don't even know how to call them in a page. I have a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thindery/SsN42/).

Can anyone show me how to use these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like those methods are contained in the jQueryUI widget factory instance for that plugin. You may be able to call the methods by calling the name as a parameter using the widget object's .data(). Check this page out for more info: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2011/09/30/jquery-ui-calling-widget-methods-directly/ or reference this StackOverflow question: [JQuery - Widget Public Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775365/jquery-widget-public-methods)