# Access autocomplete input in change event

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, closures

We have customized jQuery's autocomplete a bit and in the `change` event handler, we need to access the input to call a function we added. The `ui` parameter is the selected item, but if the user entered some random text, no item will be selected and `ui.item` is null. So I can't use traverse the DOM base on `ui.item`.

In short, what we (actually someone in the past on this project) did is modify the jquery ui file:

```
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {
    // original code here
    ourCustomMethod: function() {}
});
```

Now we have constructed a combobox in which we do (simplified):

```
var self = this;
var input = this.input = $("<input>")
    .autocomplete({
        change: function(event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                // I want to call the ourCustomMethod here
                // I can't use the parents of ui.item because it's null
            }
        }
    });
```

So how can I get access to the `ourCustomMethod`? I'm guessing through `self.input` but can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: What does your custom function do?

Comment: It's a filtering logic for the combobox, but is not really relevant. In the meantime, I've found the solution. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering this myself so quickly, but I found the answer after continuing to look around. I never really knew how to word this properly.

I found the answer here: [JQuery - Widget Public Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775365/jquery-widget-public-methods/2966921#2966921)

In my case, I could do this:

```
self.input.autocomplete('ourCustomMethod');
```

This is apparently the way to call widget methods on a DOM element, which I didn't know.